# Workbook beforesave macro

Tags: excel

Trying to use the workbook beforesave macro to save file name with Date Revision number and Time. To save the file with new name "BOOK1 - 08 Mar 2016 - Rev 001 08-59.xlsx" or if the workbook is macro-enabled .xlsm at the end. Here's the coding so far but it doesn't seem to be working or doing what it's supposed to do. Any advice appreciated.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim file_name As Variant
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strVer As String

    ' Get the file name.
    file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsx,Macro EnabledWorkbook,*.xlsm, All Files,*.*", _
        Title:="Save As File Name")

    ' check if the user has canceled.
    If file_name = False Then Exit Sub

    strDate = Format((Date), "dd MMM yyyy")
    strVer = "0"
    strVer = Val(strVer) + 1 'Increment number



    ' Save the file with the new name.
    If LCase$(Right$(file_name, 4)) <> ".xls" Then
        file_name = file_name  & " - " & strDate & _
    " - Rev " & Format(Val(strVer), "00# ") _
    & Format(Time(), "hh-mm") & ".xls"
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name
   End Sub
```

Comment: strVer will be always number one since it is a procedure level variable.  Then right() function is arriving 4 characters and you are trying to match it with three characters. (.xls)

Comment: "t it doesn't seem to be working or doing what it's supposed to do" What is it doing? What is it supposed to do? Have you identified the line in the code where things stop doing what you expect/desire? Go in the code and press f8 to debug it line by line, hovering over variables to see their values at any point in time.

Comment: I need to use the before save workbook event to capture the name the user provides and then append Date Rev and Time to the workbook before saving it.

Comment: Also user should have choice to save as *.xls, *.xlsx or *.xlsm file.

Comment: Graham, in the initial instance you must save the workbook as you normally do by giving it a file name. Then when you save the workbook via the macro it will add the date-revision-time to the filename. I have not got it to work with a new file from the outset. That is what I'm still trying to do or doing a save as and have the revision numbering start from 1 again.